# how to extract multiple function output automatially in R

Tags: r

I have built my own function, where it returns many values. I really need to extract several values at once. For example, suppose the following is my function

```
myfunc <- function(x,y){
  res <- x+y
  res2 <- x^2
  res3 <- x*2
  
  out <- list()
  out$add <- res
  out$squ <- res2
  out$or <- res3
  out$ADD <- res+res2+res3
  out$fi <- res^2+res2+res3
  
  return(out)
}
```

Then,

```
    > myres
$add
[1] 7

$squ
[1] 9

$or
[1] 6

$ADD
[1] 22

$fi
[1] 64
```

suppose I want to extract two values at a time, for example,

```
myres$add, and myres$ADD
```

is there a way to find them automatically in R instead of repeating it. My original function is very complicated and this will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try something like this -

```
res <- myfunc(6, 4)
extract_values <- c('add', 'ADD')
res[extract_values]

#$add
#[1] 10

#$ADD
#[1] 58
```

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate them or join in a list:

> c(myres$add, myres$squ)

> list(myres$add, myres$squ)

If you only want one call to myres you could also index like this:

> myres[c(1, 2)]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is known as *destructuring*, and unfortunately R does not natively support it. There are multiple packages which support this. The one with the (IMHO) nicest syntax is my own package ‘[unpack](https://github.com/klmr/unpack/)’, which allows you to write positional unpacking as follows:

```
c[add, ., ., ADD, .] = myfunc(3, 4)
```

After this, the variables `add` and `ADD` are directly available to the caller.

A similar solution (more powerful but with a less nice syntax) is provided by the ‘[zeallot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeallot/vignettes/unpacking-assignment.html)’ package.